# How do I uninstall a Chocolatey package that won't go away?

Tags: uninstall, chocolatey

```
C:\Users\Chloe>choco uninstall cyg-get
Chocolatey v0.10.8
Uninstalling the following packages:
cyg-get

cyg-get v1.1.0
 Skipping auto uninstaller - No registry snapshot.

Chocolatey uninstalled 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

C:\Users\Chloe>choco list --local-only cyg-get
Chocolatey v0.10.8
cyg-get 1.1.0
cygwin 1.7.23.20130814
2 packages installed.
```

Comment: Can you add content of the `chocolatey.log` file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used `--force` and it went away.

```
choco uninstall cyg-get --force
```

Comment: That typically does it, you can also add `-n` to ensure it doesn't run scripts. If all else fails, head to `$env:ChocolateyInstall\lib` and remove the folder for the package.

Comment: @ferventcoder I did try `-n` but that didn't help. I see that I didn't copy that in the question. I also tried another longer `--` option it suggested that I can't remember. I believe I did try to delete a folder in a Chocolatey folder, but when I ran `upgrade all` it added it back.

Comment: It means that there was possibly an older lingering version still sitting around that needed to also be removed.

Answer (score 0):

For me the package was broken, an error when running choco uninstall --force so I uninstalled the old fashioned way and then ran choco uninstall so it removes the reference and doesn't try to upgrade it on the next run